# My questions about custom sort window in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I use MS Excel 2010 on my Win 7 machine.
In my table, when I use *custom sort* there are some odd thinks for me.

1- The "*My data has headers*" is always gray and when table has header it's checked otherwise no. But since it's gray I can't change it, why?

2- In the *custom sort* window there is a button named *Options*. When clicked it opens new small window. How does the *case sensitive* option exactly work?

3- *sort left to right* in that small previous window is always gray. How can I use it and for what?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Would have to see an example where you think its failing to be sure,
   but its probably just Excel guessing if you do/dont have headers. 
   Try selecting the table and headers, then the table without, I'm
   guessing it might change the behaviour.
2. Basically does the sort consider Capitals to be of higher 'value'
   than non-capitals.  Certian on languages this can make a more
   pronounced difference. Also see this [Office Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/sort-records-in-case-sensitive-order-HA010062760.aspx) page.
3. Sort by column or sort by row basically, if you change it and go
   back to the previous windows you can see the Sort By now lists rows
   not columns.

Answer (score 1):

For points 1 and 3:

- *My data has headers* is grey because the data you have is inside a table, which has its own version of 'My data has headers'. This may also be because Excel thinks it is without headers, to check, just select the data with headers, and see if you can use the option. If is doesn't then select the data without headers, then see.
- *Sort left to right* is also grey because the data you have is inside a table. Currently, Excel does not support 'tables' being left-to-right (I think). All this does is sort the table by row instead of column

Your screenshot shows that your data is in a table.

For point 2:

- Sorts the table by thinking of upper-case values as higher than lower-case values. Think of upper-case values as 1 and lower-case values as 0. See [this Microsoft Page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073947.aspx) for much more details on Custom Sort *in Excel*. Or [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/sort-records-in-case-sensitive-order-HA010062760.aspx) page (for Access but I think the same thing applies to Excel as well!).

Comment: Yes, my data are in a table. Probably most of the problems is from that. Look at my updated question please.

Comment: @abbasi Yes that is your problem then. To fix, you can either remove the table or (even better), just sort with those arrows on the headers. Is there any other problem? If not, please +1 and tick :)

Comment: Just one another question. Case sensitive doesn't work properly. For example if I change the "_one_" to "_One_" in "Number" column and then sort it by value and order A to Z and case sensitive enabled that _One_ again is after _Eight eleven Five Four nine_. Why?

Comment: @abbasi You need to make sure that you've selected the whole table when using case sensitivity AFAIK, I don't use that option very often... Does [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/sort-records-in-case-sensitive-order-HA010062760.aspx) help? It explains in much more detail (although for Acess - the same thing applies to Excel)

Comment: somehow. In that link, the _D_ is before (prior to) the _a_ in case sensitive. But in mine, as I wrote, it can't precede others.

Comment: @abbasi Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14800/discussion-between-shub-and-abbasi).